# Using both MySQL procedure and session db in code igniter cause `2014` error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a controller like this:

```
$r_result = $this->storedprocedure->user_email_exist($in_email);

if($r_result->num_rows() == 1)
{
    foreach ($r_result->result() as $row)
    {
       $salt = $row->salt;
       $hash = $row->hash_password;
       if(strcasecmp(Application_Helper::hash_password($aData['password'], $salt), 
          $hash)==0)
       {
           //Login success
           echo('login success');

           $newdata = array('user_id'  => $row->id);
           $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
       }
    }
}
```

In the Storedprocedure model, is something like this:

```
public function user_email_exist($aEmail)
{   
    $r_result = $this->db->query("CALL user_email_exist('".$aEmail."')");

    return $r_result;
}
```

I tested it, it can login success, but print an error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 2014
>
> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>
> UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1358764263, `user_data` =
>   'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"user_id\";s:2:\"35\";}' WHERE
>   `session_id` = '05e340b2aa6bd9b21261ed0d20354b3c'
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 289

The problem is, I must use the `MySQL procedure` to implement the model layer, but it seems that have some conflict between the ci_session. Any recommend solutions for that issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to the fact that mySQL Stored Procedures return MULTI RESULTS
even if there is only one select statement in them . Solution is to simply call $r_result->next_result() to loose the expected extraneous resultset.

I got the idea from this [link](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/73714/#562711).

please Replace the controller code like below:

```
$r_result = $this->storedprocedure->user_email_exist($in_email);

if($r_result->num_rows() == 1)
{
    $row = $r_result->row_array();
    $r_result->next_result(); // Dump the extra resultset.
    $r_result->free_result(); // Does what it says.

    $salt = $row->salt;
    $hash = $row->hash_password;
    if(
      strcasecmp(Application_Helper::hash_password($aData['password'], $salt),$hash)==0
    ) {
       //Login success
       echo('login success');

       $newdata = array('user_id'  => $row->id);
       $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Ted Wong please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, it does not work. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::next_result(). ` instead, I do this:`                   $this->db->close();`
 after Login success, at it works with no error. I don't know it is a right way to do or not.